# Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly - app.config different from packages.config

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have a solution with over 40 projects.
In most of these projects I'm using System.Net.Http which I have installed via NuGet. At the time of writing we have installed v4.3.3 from Nuget. That is also what is written into packages.config

```
<package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.3" targetFramework="net47" />
```

When I look into my app.config , I'm using different versions here. In some of my configs the version is listed as 4.1.1.2, in others its listed as 4.2.0.0. I Guess these are the internal versions, but what I find wired is that installing the same NuGet on two different projects gives me two different internal versions.

One app.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.2" newVersion="4.1.1.2" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Another app.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
 <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I have tried downgrading and then upgrading again in Nuget in order to get both the packages.config & app.config updated. And the files are updated.
But in some app.config I get another version than I get in other. With the excat same NuGet version, installed at the same time.

What gives?

I have read quite a bunch of topics here on SO, but none of them quite has the same problem. Most of the time, people fix their problem by upgrading to the latest version, that doesn't help here.

I'm guessing that I might have other references that force the version of System.Net.Http to an older version for that project, but is there any way I can confirm this thesis? Also, if that is actually the case, is it then possible to enforce all project to run the highest common version instead of different versions?

Answer (score 0):

> Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly - app.config different from packages.config

It seems that Visual Studio 2017 is shipping with a .NET 4.6.x-4.7.x `System.Net.Http.dll` with internal assembly version 4.2.0 and the latest Nuget Package assembly version is 4.1.2 for NetFX.

The author of this package Microsoft needs to release an updated nuget package with a version of 4.2.0.0.

The current workaround is probably change the bindingRedirect `4.1.1.2` to `4.2.0.0`:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>      
</assemblyBinding>
```

In this case, all the dlls are used from the build extensions directory and not the one from Nuget.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! :) Is there any way I can enforce not using the VS17 version, but instead use the NuGet version? I guess the version from NuGet is newer even though the internal version is different? Also, how did you find that VS17 is shipping with another version?

Comment: @Squazz, Starting with .NET Framework 4.7.1, we will always prefer to use the inbox System.Net.Http.dll (GAC'd version) and not any OOB (out-of-band) System.Net.Http.dll anymore from NuGet package. Please check more details from following thread: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25050 and https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25773

Comment: The only thing I have in my solution that is depending on System.Net.Http is Google.Apis. Google.Apis is used in two different projects, both targeting .Net Framework 4.7. But in some projects we use inbox, in others we use OOB. I can't find any way to enforce either OOB or Inbox, seems Nuget just decides that for us, and makes different descisions in different projects.